# Bootcamp not asking for USB

Tags: bootcamp, windows, usb

I bought a new Macbook and i'm trying to install windows on this computer with bootcamp (i added windows to my other macs too without problem) but this app won't gives me the option to choose the usb drive where he downloads the drivers and boot files... why is the first 1 - 2 step gone ? This way if the windows install starts it tells me there is a problem because no boot file is there... why i can't choose the usb ? did apple updated something ? :/ can't find any solutions... any idea ? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please have a look at this article: http://www.idownloadblog.com/2015/10/01/el-capitan-boot-camp-windows-changes/

Just follow the next steps and windows should install without using a USB drive.

Comment: ah thats meh... the article says that with this way the windows still installs without probem but why i get always a missing boot error :/... maybe i need the latest windows iso ?... i'll try with the latest original iso, Thanks for the info

Answer (score 0):

I recently had a similar problem. [Apparently](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201468#more), BootCamp Assistant doesn't require a USB-stick anymore. In my case I used [Brigadier](https://github.com/timsutton/brigadier) – a neat little tool that will identify and download the correct Bootcamp drivers for you.

Concerning your boot problem, I am not sure what is going on. Did you check that your image file is working and that [your version of Windows is supported on your Mac](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT205016#tables)?

Comment: Thanks everyone, i finally installed windows on my mac without usb... i was very confused last week i had to connect an usb and now not, but i need to use the latest windows which will start boot. Thank for the tips